# What kind of solving algorithm does linalg.solve use?

Tags: python, numpy

Just curious if it uses Gaussian elimination or some other equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html):

> solve is a wrapper for the LAPACK routines dgesv and zgesv, the former
>   being used if a is real-valued, the latter if it is complex-valued.
>   The solution to the system of linear equations is computed using an LU
>   decomposition [R40] with partial pivoting and row interchanges.

More details on [dgesv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesv.f) and [zgesv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/complex16/zgesv.f)