# Why is scipy.linalg.LU so slow for solving Ax = b repeatedly?

Tags: python, scipy

Conventional wisdom states that if you are solving Ax = b several times with the same A and a different b, you should be using an LU factorization for LU. If I use `p, l, u = scipy.linalg.lu(A)` and solve several times in a loop with

```
x = scipy.linalg.solve(l, p.T@b)
x = scipy.linalg.solve(u, x)
```

this ends up being much slower than just using

```
x = scipy.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

in the loop. Is `scipy.linalg.solve()` not optimized to solve upper and lower-diagonal systems using forward and backward substitution? Or, is it possible that there is some compiling trickery where python recognizes that it can do LU factorization for the `scipy.linalg.solve` part?

I know there are `linalg.lu_factor`  and `linalg.lu_solve` routines in scipy, but I wanted to stay away from those since this is supposed to be a pedagogical example.

Comment: What about `invA = np.linalg.inverse(A)` once, then `x = invA @ b` for every `b`?

Comment: `scipy.linalg.solve` doesn't know that there is anything special about `l` and `u`, so the results that you obtained are to be expected.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah I can see that, but it's strange. It seems like a cheap check. I am comparing to MATLAB which does this check and solves these systems much faster.

Comment: @Julien Sure, that is fast, but usually using the inverse is a bad idea due to numerical instability.

Comment: because LU-decomposition is doing Gaussian Elimination of square-matrix simultaneously - that is increasing the speed, but [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13807369/15893581) seems doing it once again

Comment: besides Lu-decomposition [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199008/15893581) reduces matrix -- try `_remove_redundancy` manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of my linear algebra studies were pre-computer (or at least pre MATLAB/python).  But I can read the docs.

```
In [29]: from scipy import linalg as la
```

Starting with a sample array from `la.lu`:

```
In [30]: A = np.array([[2, 5, 8, 7], [5, 2, 2, 8], [7, 5, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 8]])
In [31]: p, l, u = la.lu(A)
In [32]: p
Out[32]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
In [33]: l
Out[33]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.28571429,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.71428571,  0.12      ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.71428571, -0.44      , -0.46153846,  1.        ]])
In [34]: u
Out[34]: 
array([[ 7.        ,  5.        ,  6.        ,  6.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  3.57142857,  6.28571429,  5.28571429],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -1.04      ,  3.08      ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  7.46153846]])

In [42]: b=np.arange(4)
In [43]: la.solve(A,b)
Out[43]: array([-0.21649485,  2.54639175, -1.54639175,  0.01030928])
In [44]: timeit la.solve(A,b)
43.5 µs ± 88.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I see docs for a `la.solve_triangular`.  After a bit trial and error I got:

```
In [46]: la.solve_triangular(u,la.solve_triangular(l,p.T@b, lower=True))
Out[46]: array([-0.21649485,  2.54639175, -1.54639175,  0.01030928])
```

and timing it:

```
In [47]: timeit la.solve_triangular(u,la.solve_triangular(l,p.T@b, lower=True))
83 µs ± 2.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So double use of `solve_trianglar` is slower than one `solve`, but is faster than using a `solve` that doesn't know that its arrays are triangular.

```
In [48]: la.solve(u,la.solve(l,p.T@b))
Out[48]: array([-0.21649485,  2.54639175, -1.54639175,  0.01030928])
In [49]: timeit la.solve(u,la.solve(l,p.T@b))
137 µs ± 342 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I don't know how these calculations will scale.

Testing @Warren's `lu_solve` idea (in a deleted answer)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64473976/901925

```
In [50]: lu_and_piv = la.lu_factor(A)
In [51]: lu_and_piv
Out[51]: 
(array([[ 7.        ,  5.        ,  6.        ,  6.        ],
        [ 0.28571429,  3.57142857,  6.28571429,  5.28571429],
        [ 0.71428571,  0.12      , -1.04      ,  3.08      ],
        [ 0.71428571, -0.44      , -0.46153846,  7.46153846]]),
 array([2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32))
In [52]: la.lu_solve(lu_and_piv, b)
Out[52]: array([-0.21649485,  2.54639175, -1.54639175,  0.01030928])
In [53]: timeit la.lu_solve(lu_and_piv, b)
7.47 µs ± 14.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes I understand that lu_solve is much faster. The thing I was surprised by is that scipy's solve doesn't seem to check for any special structure in the matrix! Then that makes me more confused as to the supposed advantages it has over numpy's solve (which it claims it has). I guess I'll have to look at the docs and source code more carefully.

Comment: Many of these `scipy` functions are interfaces to compiled libraries.  `scipy` extends `numpy` but is not tightly integrated with it.  This is open source with many developers, without the $$ of a commercial product.

Comment: @Jeremy Upsal: numpy is fast ! as it is written in C, scipy in its implementation comprise numpy+mkl, as is wrapper for numpy, consuming some time

Comment: @hpaulj, What about `LU` based solution for non square matrices? It seems to fail.